# python: grab a specific line after a match

Tags: python, loops, lines

I have have df full of text
I would like to define variable **date** which is always three lines after **version**.
here is my code

```
with open(input_file1,'r') as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        if line.startswith('Version'):
            version = line.strip()
            date = line + 3
            print(line,date)
```

but it does not work for the **date** variable and i receive the following error. Can anybody help?

```
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly
```

Comment: It isn't exactly clear what you're trying to do. `line` is a string which you can't add to `int` 3

Comment: Yes would like to define variable **date** which is always three lines after version. I am not sure how to do that

Comment: the enumerate() is lazy - which means you don't have the other lines available in that exact moment. They will be "read" when they are needed. If you want to get the other 3 lines you would need to load the complete file before and then slice it or you have to use a state mechanism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`line` is the string contents of the line in the file. `i` is the incrementally increasing index of the line being parsed. Therefore you want to read line number `i+3`. You can read three lines ahead easily if you read all the lines into memory with `.readlines()`.
**NOTE** this is not advisable if your files are very large!

```
with open(input_file1,'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for i, line in enumerate(lines):
        if line.startswith('Version'):
            version = line.strip()
            date = lines[i + 3].strip()
            print(line,date)
```

Answer (score 0):

What the error message is telling you is that you cannot add a number to a string.

You first need to convert the string to a datetime object, to which you can then add anything you want.

Check out the [datetime documentation here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html).

In your case, you might want to try something like:

```
import datetime
Date = datetime.datetime.strptime(line, "%m/%d/%Y")
```

Where the second set of arguments determine the format of the date you are feeding the datetime object via your line variable. You will have to change this bit ("%m/%d/%Y") to match your input.